Simple Postgres Table Insert Think I'm Using An Array
Oracle veteran here, new to postgres.  As an example, I have a table defined as (col1 varchar(10),col2 inteter,col3 varchar(20).  I issue this statement from the Query Tool in pgadmin:
insert into tablename values('First Name',23,'Last Name');
and I get these messages:
ERROR:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.malformed array literal: "First Name"
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "First Name"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
Character: 28
As far as I know, I haven't said anything about an array.  I just want to insert 3 fields as 1 row of data.  Every "insert into" example I've found, including using a .csv file, seem straightforward and work fine.  Not for me!  Am I doing something wrong syntactically or what?
I tried what the examples suggested, expecting it to work.

My guess is that: 1) This col1 varchar(10) is actually something like this col1 varchar[]. or 2) You have table named tablename in more then one schema and since you are not schema qualifying the table it is finding the other schema that has a different type definition.

Check the DDL for this table, you created an array and because this the INSERT wants an array as input.

Many thanks!  Yes, I didn't bother to take the time to learn the differences of the various datatypes available.  I specified character varying[], which is the array thing, apparently.  My mistake for not investigating.  Thanks again!
